# F# file formatting with visual studio code

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, ionide

I'm starting using VS code with F# and dotnet core. I've installed ionide extension but file formatting for F# is not working. How did you get it working in vs code?.

Answer (score 3):

> Visual Studio Code will not react if the user presses Shift + Alt + F.
>   On the contrary, Visual Studio F# Power Tools support code formatting.

There is an open issue:
[F# Source Code Formatting #274](https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/274)